# how to delete multi row in sqlite ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I am trying to delete multi rows:
I am using this code:

```
    [db beginTransaction];
       [db executeUpdate:@"delete FROM tasks  WHERE _id NOT LIKE \'temp\%\' andD _id NOT LIKE \'\%prepop\%\' AND _id NOT LIKE \'link\%\'"];
    [db commit];
```

For some reason the data is not been deleted ...

Comment: There seems to by at least one typo: `andD`. You *did* copy/paste your real code, didn't you?

Comment: You should check the result code of `executeUpdate` and if not `YES`, then log `[db lastErrorMessage]` and that will tell you where the problem is in your SQL. The error is the `andD` typo. As an aside, while it's not an error, all of those backslashes are unnecessary.

Comment: No i didn't .. but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo:

```
andD
```

should be:

```
AND
```

However as your statement is illegal you should be getting an error back, so you need to pay more attention to catching and reporting errors.

(Just noticed that @MartinR spotted this immediately so props to him).